Laravel 10 CORS issue fix
I am trying to remove CORS error in my api's but its not working properly. I am using CORS Middleware to remove CORS error, and its working fine with many of my API's but its not working with some API's. In some of APIs, I am using third party IP to fetch data, that's why its not working. The APIs in which the IP is used, only in that its giving CORS error, otherwise its fine.
I have also tried to install fruitcake/laravel-cors but unfortunately its not installing.
How can I resolve this CORS error?
